# ASP.NET MVC 3 - how to code data annotations and jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been bashing my head against a brick wall for the past 3 days trying to code a way round the following scenario - it must be a fairly common scenario, but I'm a database designer and very new to MVC3 and C#

I have 2 database tables:

`Primary_Applicant_Details` and `Previous_Applicant_Details`

These tables have a primary key and the following fields:

```
Title     not null
Forenames not null
Surname   not null
```

Now, the view contains the fields of both of these tables (using Mindscape Lightspeed to generate the model), however, the user MUST enter the Primary details, thus data annotations of "required" - works fine.

But, the Previous Applicant Details are optional.

So, if the user enters any of the Previous Applicant Details, i.e. Title, Forenames or Surname, then ALL of these items on the view MUST be entered.

So I can't put "Required" data annotation on the Previous Applicant Details fields as this will make them mandatory in the view.

Is the only way to build a requiredif data annotation?  If it is it would need to be on all 3 fields and check the other 2 fields have been entered. i.e. If title is entered then check that forenames and surname have been entered too, if forenames is entered check taht title and surname has been entered, etc.

If this is correct, can anyone help in providing the code for a data annotation that checks for multiple fields? 
If there is another way round this scenario, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing built into MVC3 but [this guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx) has built a mvc 3 validation toolkit that has "conditional required" validation.

Comment: So, it would seem that MVC 3 is only good for "simple" websites where simple validation rules exist, whereas my scenario is a more "complex"?  Would you agree?

Comment: Not at all in fact Stack OVerflow is built on asp.net MVC. There is an entire framework for building whatever validation you wish.  It is just that the built in, out of the box validation covers the 80% of common cases, the 20% of complex cases you simply have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own custom validator.
To do this you must inherit from the ValidationAttribute class and override the IsValid method. There is a cool overload for the IsValid method which allows you to get access to the current context so you can then check all the properties on your model, do database lookups that kind of thing.

Check out this great article for all the finer points on data validation. It should help you solve your problem.

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/19/spelunking-inside-aspnet-mvc-3-model-aware-data-annotations